# Sorting coordinates

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, sorting

Im coding a Paint version for Minecraft with the CC Tweaked Mod
The Problem is i give my program an array and the program follows the order of the array one after the other.

That means if i draw something in the top left and then bottom right and then i fill everything else it will follow this order (which isnt very efficient)

I have an array called output
Here is how the array could look like

```
[
  { x: 0, y: 0, color: 12 },
  { x: 1, y: 0, color: 3 },
  { x: 2, y: 0, color: 5 },
  { x: 0, y: 1, color: 8 },
  { x: 1, y: 1, color: 10 },
  { x: 2, y: 1, color: 11 },
  { x: 0, y: 2, color: 12 },
  { x: 2, y: 2, color: 3 },
  { x: 1, y: 2, color: 14 }
]
```

[image]

The array comes from this "drawing"(ignore the arrows for now)

Now the question
How can i get from the first array to an array that looks like this

```
[
  { x: 0, y: 0, color: 12 },
  { x: 1, y: 0, color: 3 },
  { x: 2, y: 0, color: 5 },
  { x: 2, y: 1, color: 11 },
  { x: 1, y: 1, color: 10 },
  { x: 0, y: 1, color: 8 },
  { x: 0, y: 2, color: 12 },
  { x: 1, y: 2, color: 14 }
  { x: 2, y: 2, color: 3 },
]
```

(See how it follows the arrows?)

This would be much faster.

It is possibles that some squares are not filled with any color. Idk how important that might be

If important these are the colorcodes

```
const LISTOFCOLORS = {
    white: 1,
    orange: 2,
    magenta: 3,
    dodgerblue: 4,
    yellow: 5,
    lime: 6,
    pink: 7,
    gray: 8,
    lightgray: 9,
    cyan: 10,
    purple: 11,
    blue: 12,
    SaddleBrown: 13,
    green: 14,
    red: 15,
    black: 16
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only reversing the `3 - 6` entries, you could create a new array from slices of the old array using `slice()` and reverse the specified entries using `reverse()`.

```js
const rowByRow = [
  { x: 0, y: 0, color: 12 },
  { x: 1, y: 0, color: 3 },
  { x: 2, y: 0, color: 5 },
  { x: 0, y: 1, color: 8 },
  { x: 1, y: 1, color: 10 },
  { x: 2, y: 1, color: 11 },
  { x: 0, y: 2, color: 12 },
  { x: 2, y: 2, color: 3 },
  { x: 1, y: 2, color: 14 }
];

const result = [
  ...rowByRow.slice(0, 3), 
  ...rowByRow.slice(3, 6).reverse(), // reverse 3 - 6 entries 
  ...rowByRow.slice(6, 9)
];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The example i used is kinda dumb for a SO question. The Array i gave isnt not like this. Remeber that this is a painting program and users normally dont go from left to right. If i could get the array first in this format your solution would work

Comment: But the slicing part is interesting. If i could make multiple arrays where every array is assigned one y coordinate i could sort these array by the x coordinate and stick them back together

Comment: @Venox you can try some things out using this method. If you could update your question with a bit more specific info I could follow it up.

Answer (score 1):

@axtck Thank you very much. I ended up not using slice but the "slicing the array in multiple arrays and work from there" part i got from your post

i ended up with this

```
const arr = [
    { x: 1, y: 4, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 4, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 3, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 2, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 0, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 4, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 2, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 3, color: 12 },
    { x: 0, y: 3, color: 12 },
    { x: 0, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 0, y: 2, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 2, color: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 4, color: 12 },
    { x: 4, y: 4, color: 12 },
    { x: 4, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 4, y: 2, color: 12 },
    { x: 4, y: 3, color: 12 },
    { x: 0, y: 4, color: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 3, color: 12 }
]

const ArrayOfArrays = []
const dimension = 5

for (let i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {

    let array = []


    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (i == arr[j].y) {
            array.push(arr[j])
        }
    }

    ArrayOfArrays.push(i % 2 === 0 ?
        array.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.x - b.x;
        }) : array.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.x - a.x;
        }))

}





console.log(ArrayOfArrays)
```

The output would be

```js
[
  [
    { x: 0, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 0, color: 12 },
    { x: 4, y: 0, color: 12 }
  ],
  [
    { x: 4, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 1, color: 12 },
    { x: 0, y: 1, color: 12 }
  ],
  [
    { x: 0, y: 2, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 2, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 2, color: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 2, color: 12 },
    { x: 4, y: 2, color: 12 }
  ],
  [
    { x: 4, y: 3, color: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 3, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 3, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 3, color: 12 },
    { x: 0, y: 3, color: 12 }
  ],
  [
    { x: 0, y: 4, color: 12 },
    { x: 1, y: 4, color: 12 },
    { x: 2, y: 4, color: 12 },
    { x: 3, y: 4, color: 12 },
    { x: 4, y: 4, color: 12 }
  ]
]
```

notice how the x value goes up and down